# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Multi-tenancy and Active Directory Account Creation Mode

Tags: multi-tenancy, ad-account-creation-mode

Does anyone know if SharePoint 2010 Foundation multi-tenancy works if you install the farm in Active Directory Account Creation mode?  I am able to use STSADM to create host header site collections but not New-SPSite passing the subscription id.  I get a useless error along the lines of operation failed please try again in ULS logs...

Comment: @sharkmu25: It doesn't mention account creation mode specifically but I wanted to point out the great series of articles about multi-tenancy on Share-n-dipity, starting with http://blogs.technet.com/speschka/archive/2009/11/30/enabling-multi-tenant-support-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex, thanks for your ideas.  I have followed that Share-n-dipity series.  I have come to the conclusion that multi-tenancy is not supported with AD account creation mode because AD account creation mode puts ALL users in a single OU.  Multi-tenancy allows you to create a separate OU per tentant.  We are moving away from AD account creation mode as it is troublesome for migrations\upgrades.

Thanks!

Comment: @sharkmu25: I think that's a very good idea. Someone at my workplace has confirmed account creation mode is present in SP2010 but it is still deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Account Creation Mode was supposed to be deprecated in WSS 3.0 but the document that contained that information has had that line removed.

[This link on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383248%28office.14%29.aspx) may help you troubleshoot getting it working. I don't know if it is supported with multi-tenancy.